# Why is my node express app not fetching data from mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a background in PHP MVC and just started learning Nodejs. 
This is my app directory structure:

root
    - controllers
        -user.js
    - model
        -user.js
    - public
        -stylesheet
            -style.css
    - views
        -index.jade
    - app.js
    - package.json
    - gulpfile.js

This is my controller file: user.js

```
var User = require('../models/user.js');

exports.list = function(req, res){
  User.find(function(err, users) {
    res.send(users);
  });
};
```

This is my model file: user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/mydb');

var userSchema = new Schema({
name: String,
country: String,
email: String,
password: String,
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

Below is my app.js file:

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

```
var express = require('express')
, controllers = require('./controllers')
, employee = require('./controllers/employee')
, user = require('./controllers/user')
, http = require('http')
, path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));



app.get('/', controllers.index);
app.get('/employees', employee.list);
app.get('/user',user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

I have created a database in mongo using the command line and below is my collections list:

[image]

I may still be thinking it the php way and missing some point here. Could someone point out what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Db name should be `users`

Comment: Or more to the point, since as @Yerken mentions your current "collection" name is `user` and not `users` as mongoose is expecting, then instead define the model as `mongoose.model("user",userSchema,"user")`. Where the "third" argument sets the collection name.

Comment: @Yerken Thank you! renaming the database from "user" to "users" actually did the trick. Also, it did not matter if I used: module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema); or module.exports = mongoose.model('users', userSchema); after the database was renamed.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose automatically looks for the [plural version of your model name](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html), more details about this rule please refer to the [source code](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/utils.js#L44), [`Mongoose.model`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-model) definition is

```
Mongoose#model(name, [schema], [collection], [skipInit])
```

To solve your issue, you could define your model

```
 mongoose.model('user', userSchema, { collection: 'user' });
```